# Why my Manageiq Integerated with openstack is not getting refreshed?

Tags: refresh, instance, integration, openstack-horizon, manageiq

My ManageIQ is been integrated with Openstack, previously refreshing was working fine. But after some migrations happened in Openstack, after then the changes is not reflecting in ManageIQ.

Comment: Shakthi, for clarification, which version of ManageIQ and Openstack are you using?

Comment: @AndreiVeselov My Miq version ivanchuk-3 and openstack version is Queens. I think problem is from openstack because morethan 3 MIQ's is been integrated  with openstack, none of them is getting is refreshed.